# Linq query throws an error

Tags: c#, linq

I get an exception

> The expression cannot be evaluated. A common cause of this error is attempting to pass a lambda into a delegate.

My code:

```
using (var context = new LorikeetAppEntities())
{
    try
    {
        if (listBoxControlMembers.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            var memberToRemove = listBoxControlMembers.SelectedItem.ToString().Split(' ');

            LorikeetDataLib.Member memberTemp = (from m in context.Members
                                                 where (m.FirstName.Contains(memberToRemove[0]) && m.Surname.Contains(memberToRemove[1]))
                                                 select m).First();

            membersToAdd.Add(memberTemp);
            members.Remove(memberTemp);

            textBoxMemberFilter.Text = "";
            RefreshMembers("");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(MiscStuff.GetAllMessages(ex));
    }
}
```

I have tried lots of things but nothing seems to work.

Comment: You get the exception at `First()`? So a breakpoint at `membersToAdd.Add` is not get hit?

Comment: I don't think you can call `Contains` like that on a string in EF.

Comment: This is not a `Linq` problem. You may want to tag it with the technology you are using. Is it Entity Framework?

Comment: Without knowing which type of LINQ you're in this question goes down as "unclear what you're asking".